Navigating a higher dimensional space with fewer controls
Think of an Etch-a-Sketch:

You have two knobs to navigate a two dimensional space: up/down and left/right.
Now imagine you have a three-dimensional space but still only two knobs. Is there some way to map those two knobs to the three dimensions such that you can still move the pointer anywhere in the space? I won't ask you to draw the Taj Mahal with it!
Additional requirements:

should be deterministic
reversing a sequence of moves should return you to where you started. i.e. starting at point X and turning knob A one turn right, then knob B one turn right, then know B one turn left and knob A one turn left should bring you back to X.
but that doesn't need to be the case if mixing up the order of moves. e.g. starting at X and moving knob A one turn right, then knob B one turn right, then knob A one turn left, then knob B one turn left does not need to bring you back to X, as it would on a normal Etch-a-sketch.

The use case for this is controlling the many parameters of a synthesiser (which may be in the hundreds) using a smaller number of knobs (in the single digits).

Which 3-dimensional space do you have in mind? For instance, it could be Euclidean or spherical,... From the algebraic viewpoint, you are asking if a Lie algebra can be generated by two elements.

Good point: I was imagining Euclidean.

You should edit your question to make this clear since, for instance, John's answer describes a different 3-dimensional space.


Yes, there's such a control system.

It's completely impractical for general use to reduce the number of controls from hundreds down to "a few".


I'm going to show you a 3-dimensional space and a two-control system for it.
The space consists of all possible positions and orientations for your car (let's say "positions within a large parking lot", so we can treat it as a plane). I'm going to compute orientations 'without wraparound.' You'll start pointing due north, and if you turn hard left and drive until you do two full circles, and return to pointing due north, I'll call that +720, not zero. So I hope it's clear that this constitutes a 3D space.
Here are the two controls:

the steering wheel
a modified accelerator pedal: it's a handle, and when you push it forward, the car goes faster and faster forward; when you pull it back, the car goes more and more in reverse. (Many small motorboats now have a handle like this, where 'neutral' is a straight-up position for the handle.

It's not hard to see that this system is reversible (although operating the two controls is not commutative, which is what your third bullet seems to be suggesting). And given that we can all parallel-park with enough training, and can drive anywhere and end up pointing in any direction, it's pretty clear that we can reach the whole state space.
There's the annoyance that turning the steering wheel while stopped doesn't actually change the state in any way. Arguably the state is actually 5 dimensional: $S = (x, y, \theta, c_1, c_2)$, where $\theta$ represents the angle the car is pointing, and $c_1$ and $c_2$ represent the positions of the controls. Only the first three components of this state are things we care about "controlling", though.
You can actually write down the state space and the vector fields defined by the controls, and see that they are not involutive (i.e., $[P, Q]$ is not a linear combination of $P$ and $Q$), which is more or less what's required for the set of reachable states to be more than 2D, but I feel as if that's really more than you need here. The real lesson is that learning to drive is hard, and you probably don't want to include that hardness in a user interface unless you have to.
